# Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

I'm writing a Rails project, and using `rvm ruby-1.9.3-p362`.

In my gemfile I have:

```
ruby 1.9.3
gem 'rails', '3.1.0' 
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

I also do `bundle install` and restart the Rails server, but when I'm running it in the browser it gets a console error.

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: refer https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails

Answer (score 4):

To include the `jquery-ui-rails` assets in your CSS or JS manifest you need to call

In your `application.js` manifest

```
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

And in your `application.css` manifest

```
*= require jquery.ui.all
```

Comment: carlosramireziii's answer is correct. I switched from using

`//= require jquery-ui`

to

`//= require jquery.ui.all` and I was able to compile my assets normally.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue with jquery-ui-rails(4.1.2). For 4.1.2, there is no need of using jquery.ui.all.